# Settimeout in jquery for dynamic table creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I was trying to create a dynamic table with contents from jQuery. Also I have enabled a `setTimeout` in order for the data to be refreshed and updated in the html page.`

```js
$(document).ready(function update_data() {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/wirelessSensor/dag",
    success: updateForData,
    error: errorOnAjax
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    update_data();
  }, 5000);

});

function updateForData(data) {
  // Updates DAG
  console.log("Wirless nodes details");
  var hasData = true;

  if (data.result && data.result && data.result == "none") {
    console.log('No data in result');
    hasData = false;
  } else if (!data.devices || !data.status) {
    console.log('Devices not found in result');
    hasData = false;
  }

  if (hasData) {

    console.log('Creating Table');

    var trHTML = '';
    $.each(data.devices, function(index) {

      trHTML += "<tr><td>" + data.devices[index] + "</td><td>" + data.lifetime[index] + "</td><td>" + data.status[index] + "</td></tr>";
    });

    $("#location").append(trHTML);
  }
}


function errorOnAjax(jqxhr, status, errorstr) {
  var errText = (errorstr == null) ?
    '' : ', error: ' + errorstr;
  console.log('Ajax error: ' + status + errText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="location" border='1' width='100%'>
  <tr>
    <th align='center'> Devices </th>
    <th align='center'> Lifetime </th>
    <th align='center'> Status </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here since am using `setTimeout` my dynamic table is getting duplicated. The entries already existing are been repeated. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restructure your HTML to include `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements, and the set the contents of the `<tbody>` to the results (rather than appending results to entries that might already be present).

```
<table id="location" border='1' width='100%'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align='center'> Devices </th>
      <th align='center'> Lifetime </th>
      <th align='center'> Status </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="location-content"></tbody>
</table>
```

Then do `$("#location-content").html(trHTML);` (note: `html` instead of `append`, to destroy old results instead of keeping them)

Comment: Thanks :). But now i am missing my headers . How can I include those in my table?

Comment: @NTP Ah, in that case, make sure your headers aren't in the same elements as your table body. I suggest using `<thead>` and `<tbody>` (and then write results to `<tbody>`). I edited the answer.